# Anomaly in "add" method of BigInt object

Tags: java

I created a `BigInt` class that stores the value as an `ArrayList` and a boolean flag to indicate whether the `BigInt` is negative or not. I have an `add` function that returns a `BigInt` object but it always returns an object with value `0` even if I manually set the `ArrayList` of the object.

Here is the source code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class BigInt {
ArrayList<Integer> values; // arrayList to hold the value of the BigInt
    boolean isNegative; // boolean to tell if the BigInt is negative or not

public BigInt add(BigInt other) {
    int longest = longerLength(other);
    String temp = "";
    int overflow = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < longest; i++) {
        int x = values.get(i);
        int y = other.values.get(i);
        if (x + y + overflow < 10) {
            temp += (x + y + overflow);
            overflow = 0;
        } else {
            temp += ((x + y + overflow) % 10);
            overflow = 1;
        }

    }
    if(overflow == 1)
        temp+=1;
    temp = reverse(temp);
    char[] ar = temp.toCharArray();
    BigInt sum = new BigInt(temp);
    return sum;
}

public BigInt() {
    values = new ArrayList<>();
    values.add(0);
    isNegative = false;
}
public BigInt(String str) {
    values = new ArrayList<>();
    char[] cA = str.toCharArray();
    if (cA[0] == '-') {
        cA = Arrays.copyOfRange(cA, 1, cA.length);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(cA));
        isNegative = true;
    }
    for (int i = cA.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        values.add(Character.getNumericValue(cA[i]));
    }

}
public String toString() {
        if(values.get(0)==0)
            return "0";
        String sum = "";
        
        for (int a : values) {
            sum += a;
        }
            sum += isNegative ? "-" : "";
            sum.trim();
            return new StringBuilder(sum).reverse().toString();
        }
    private String reverse(String str) {
            char[] ca = str.toCharArray();
            String solution = "";
            for (int i = ca.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
                solution += Character.getNumericValue(ca[i]);
            }
            return solution;
        }
private int longerLength(BigInt other) {
        return values.size() > other.values.size() ? values.size() : other.values.size();
    }
}
```

When I run this code below, it return a `BigInt` with value `0` instead of the expected `110`.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Tester {

public static void main(String[] args) {
System.out.println("-----------testing add------------");
        BigInt e2 = new BigInt(55);
        BigInt e3 = new BigInt(55);
        e2 = e2.add(e3);
        System.out.println(e2.toString());
}
```

Comment: We will likely have to see the rest of the class. Also, we have to see _how_ you are inspecting the result and came to the conclusion that it is `0`. Please post a [mcve]. Voting to close because missing debugging details.

Comment: Also, I do need some help making a negative number work, I decided to store the negative as a boolean, separate from the arraylist containing the value of the object

Comment: The code which you posted doesn't compile.  If you got the program to run, then you should post that code.

Comment: John - I don't think people are going to be able to help you unless you post a proper [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Code that doesn't compile is (by definition) not reproducible.  Your choice ...

Comment: *"Sorry If the formatting of the question is bad, it is my first time and I am in need of assistance."* - It is the content that is the problem; i.e. the information.  Not the formatting.

Comment: I have updated the post, hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the beginning of the toString function, you are returning "0" whenever element 0 of the values list is 0.  Are you sure you want to do that?  I don't think you do.  I believe your program prints 110 if you remove that code.

But - in your main function, you are calling the BigInt constructor with the number 55, not the string "55" which keeps your code from compiling at all.

Comment: THANK YOU I must have missed that. And sorry I also have a constructor for longs